# Xdialog - Capture user and password for a shellscript

Tags: shell-script, gui, dialog

I'm trying to create a simple "User and Password" GUI input for a shellscript, with the `--2inputbox` parameter for the `Xdialog` command:

[image]

While following the documentation seems to be easy, it does not provides additional tips on how to create this box, and it's a nightmare to do this on a "try based approach" and get a "segmentation fault" every time I try and it does not work. As far as I could get is to create a user input using a `--inputbox`.

```
Xdialog --title "RDP" --backtitle "RDP Access" --no-cancel --inputbox "Login:" 10 20
```

[image]

If I replace `--inputbox` with `--2inputbox` and put a `--password=2`(field 2) at the end of this sentence, `Xdialog`crashes. Tried other variations of those switches without success.

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not show the modified script (and gives no clues regarding how the program was installed).

If you omitted the label and initial values for the two input-fields, `Xdialog` will show the usage message (a rather large screen) rather than trying to pinpoint the problem.

This script works for me (using a one-off compile from [source](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=Xdialog) on CentOS 6):

```
Xdialog --title "RDP Company" \
        --icon company_logo.xpm \
        --no-cancel \
        --left \
        --password=2 \
        --separator="\n" \
        --2inputsbox "Type your credentials\nto access the system" 20 40 "Login(user): " "" "Password: " ""
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I edited your answer to put some "fancy" decorations(company logo) and changed the user/password separator from `/` to `newline`  :) `--backtitle` was no longer needed since the `--2inputsbox` description field was doing the job to advice the user about what to do.